# C# '..' directory exists somehow

Tags: c#, console

So I'm currently working on a Console application and I have a navigation system with the 'cd' command to move up. To make sure you haven't entered a path I check for the directory with `Directory.Exists("..")`, but this returns true in some way. Even if I enter that in the Immediate window in Visual Studio it returns true, and I'm not sure what is causing that.
Any help is welcome!

A code example:

```cs
    string path = "..";
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
        // Some code that shouldn't run but does
    else
        // Some more code that should run but doesn't
``
```

Comment: Can you share a more complete code sample? It's a bit hard to figure out what you're trying to do now.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you're expecting? Why should `Directory.Exists("..")` **not** return true?

Comment: Going to the parent directory is called moving up by the way not down. Or did you misinterpreted what `cd ..`does?

Comment: @Ralf oh i'm sorry i'll correct that

Comment: @Xerillio well because on my pc, the '..' directory does not exist, so I would say it should return false

Comment: @WouterdeKort I've updated the question and added a code example

Comment: @Jonathan `".."` means "the parent directory of **the current directory**". That means it **always** exists (even for the root directory, `".."` will point to the root directory itself).

Comment: @Xerillio oh wait, now I realize it. Thank you! Do you possibly now how to work around that?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to work around? It's perfectly valid, why should it not be? The parent folder exists, what else do you want to happen?

Comment: It is working now, thank you all for helping!

Comment: It exists, just not a subdirectory and not absolute path

Comment: Probably a useful case to handle is when "the target is not within the current working directory".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the comments, '..' means the parent directory, so it of course `Directory.Exists("..")`  returns true. I didn't know this was a thing in C#, but this saves me some code and time! Again, thanks everybody for the help!